# Platform Encryption in Developer Edition

Tags: developer-edition, platform-encryption

I am working on this [trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/spe_admins) related to Platform Encryption, enabled platform encryption and generated tenant secret keys. Further I could not find link to navigate and choose fields that I wish to encrypt. any ideas - why this is missing?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please click on the encrypt fields to select the fields you want to encrypt. Below is the screenshot you can refer. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sudipta for highlighting it, can not believe how did I missed it !. seems like sometimes we need spy's eyes.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Custom fields can be encrypted from field properties directly ... Navigate to the field and click edit ... check encrypted

[image]

Comment: it's about platform encryption and marked answer clarifies. Thanks!